# Get Windows 10 App Horribly Broken

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

This isn't filling me with optimism at the moment.  I have the Get Windows 10 tray icon but when I click on it I see this monstrosity:

[image]

Clicking on any of the links does nothing at all.  Very briefly, more like flickering, a message appears at the top of the screen saying "Please wait ..." and then nothing at all happens.

To be honest I'm running such a monsterous install of Windows 7 (I'm a developer and have a lot on this machine) that the idea of upgrading a major OS version makes me a little nervous.

Since I cannot get anything to work from this screen I cannot run the "Check your PC" option anyway.

Has anyone else seen this and have a solution?

**UPDATE 4 June**

I have tried factory resetting IE and switching my default browser back to IE and rebooted with the same result.

I can connect to VPNs and the only firewall I have in use is the normal Windows software firewall and my home network Router.

When I visit http://previewregistrationcr3.trafficmanager.net/

I see this:

[image]

Comment: The application is using your IE settings.  So if your IE settings are restricting in some capacity, the behavior on in the screenshot, would be would be exlained by that restriction.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue.  I have just set IE as my default browser again, I also then reset all the settings in the Options dialog and rebooted the machine.  Exactly the same situation, brokwn UI and links do nothing at all.

Comment: You have all other updates installed?  I can guarantee you that this is a configuration problem on your end, we just have to figure, what it could be.

Comment: Yes I keep this machine completely up to date.  I just forced a check and there aren't any update to apply.  Very odd.

Comment: Do you have a 3rd party firewall installed?

Comment: This is the reason I think its a configuration problem, the way the page is displayed, is exactly what happens if I load Superuser's secure login page here at work, and I am behind a proxy and a firewall.  Can you connect to a VPN by chance( or are you maybe already connected )?

Comment: No 3rd party firewall other than the windows software one and the normal deal with a router.

Comment: I don't use any VPNs

Comment: I have the same exact problem.  what do we have in common?  I have avast as anti-virus, chrome default browser, can't think of anything else.  this problem reminds me of skype. however the fix doesn't apply. for skype login it had to do with style sheets and permissions.  by the way I think the links work, but the css not work properly so you don't see the correct section.  I also don't have third party firewall nor vpn.  but avast may have some firewall features?

Comment: Bingo!!  I have the same issues with Skype as well!  Not found a fix for this yet which is amazing.  I asked on the technet forum and on Toms Hardware.  Nada, nothing.  Not even from Microsoft!!

Comment: When happens when you open http://previewregistrationcr3.trafficmanager.net/ in Internet Explorer

Comment: @asdasd I've updated the question with a screen grab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have now fixed this issue.

The solution was to edit a registry entry.  So using `regedit`.

1. locate this key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.css
2. The Content Type will be "application/x-css"
3. Change this to "text/css"

Problem fixed!